# JS regex search for phone number pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing tests to check if a string contains a pattern that matches typical US phone number patterns.  The particular case that is giving me trouble is this:

```js
function telephoneCheck(str) {
  if(/^|\D+\d{3}\D+\d{3}\D+\d{4}$/.test(str)) {return 0;}
  return 1;
}

console.log(telephoneCheck("(6505552368)"));
```

My particular question is: With the \D+ inside the regex and the $ at the end, why does the function return 0 for the argument given?  I understood that the \D+ would look for ONE OR MORE non-digit characters and the $ would look for the end of the string.  With no non-digits between the digits and a closing paren at the end I was expecting the regex.test(str) === false.

Comment: your pattern starts out with `^|` which effectively matches everything. It basically says "match for beginning of string, OR [the rest of your pattern]

Comment: May I recommend simply removing all the non-digit characters and then formatting the remainder instead? That way users don't need to conform to your expectations and you will be left with a nice clean format.

Comment: @CrayonViolent Thanks for the quick reply.  Ok, I was attempting to look for the start of the string OR a non digit.  I corrected it to /^\D* and it works now.  Thanks!

Comment: My next statement was going to be along @Owen 's. Save yourself the headache. Either make individual fields for each component, or just strip all non-digits and count.

Comment: @Owen The problem I'm solving requires that the non digits follow one of a few patterns (not described in my problem) so I cannot.  But thanks.  Edit: its an exercise with set test arguments so designing the input is not possible, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what your redex string should look like

```
/^\D*\d{3}\D+\d{3}\D+\d{4}$/
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  I think as per Crayon Violent, in a comment on my question, the or (|) shouldn't be there.  Without it, this works.